# Errors when using functions with multiple inputs

Tags: matlab, function, ode, function-handle

I am trying to evaluate a duffing oscillator in MATLAB with multiple inputs, and I am getting an odd error I was hoping someone might be able to help me with.

Here is the code:

```
% file duffing.m

function dy=duffing(t,y,a,b,d,g,w) 
    dy=[y(2); -a*y(1)^3-b*y(1)-d*y(2)+g*cos(w*t)];
end
```

And the file that calls the duffing function:

```
t=0:0.01:100;

%duffing oscillator 

y0=[2,0];
a=1;
b=-1;
d=0.2;
w=1;
g=0.1;

% duffing oscillator
[t,y]=ode45('duffing',t,y0,a,b,d,g,w);
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

> Error using odearguments (line 92)
>   DUFFING returns a vector of length 1, but the length of initial conditions vector is 2. The vector returned by DUFFING and the initial conditions vector must have the same number of elements.

But when I define the function duffing as

```
function dy=duffing(t,y) 

    a=1;
    b=-1;
    d=0.2;
    w=1;
    dy=[y(2); -a*y(1)^3-b*y(1)-d*y(2)+g*cos(w*t)];

end
```

and pass in

```
[t y]=ode45('duffing',t,y0);
```

with the same `y0` as above, it runs fine and I can plot it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ode45` takes as input a function of two variables only. If you want to pass more inputs, you have to create a little anonymous function, like this:

```
a=1;
b=-1;
d=0.2;
w=1;
g=0.1;

% duffing oscillator
[t,y]=ode45(@(t,y) duffing(t,y,a,b,d,g,w),t,y0);
```

Comment: This works too, and I think this is what I was going for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for `ode45` is:

```
function varargout = ode45(ode,tspan,y0,options,varargin)
```

The fourth argument, `options`, is an options struct created with `odeset`.  The additional inputs need to be the **fifth and later**, and the function needs to be modified.  The official way is to use a function handle or global variables, but here's how to do it with arguments to `ode45`.

```
options = odeset('RelTol',1e-4);
[t,y]=ode45('duffing',t,y0,options,a,b,d,g,w);
```

Then you have to modify `duffing` with a dummy argument to be compatible with the calling convention of odearguments.m (`f(t,y,'',p1,p2...)`):

```
function dy=duffing(t,y,~,a,b,d,g,w) 
    dy=[y(2); -a*y(1)^3-b*y(1)-d*y(2)+g*cos(w*t)];
end
```

The official function handle solution looks something like this:

```
myDuffing = @(t,y) duffing(t,y,a,b,d,g,w);
```

Then call `ode45` the same way as your second approach, but with `myDuffing` (see [David's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26794911/2778484) for this method).

Comment: Oh my god it worked. I edited the function to look like

    function dy=duffing(t,y,nil,a,b,d,g,w) 
        dy=[y(2); -a*y(1)^3-b*y(1)-d*y(2)+g*cos(w*t)];
    end

and I call the function with 

    [t y]=ode45('duffing',t,y0,odeset,a,b,d,g,w);